# How to display custom error message for locked users

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm currently using a wso2is 5.11.0 with a custom login page that is working fine. But i want to be able to display on the screen a custom error message when the user is locked, and tried to log in.

I was able to display a custom error message, if the user tries to log using wrong credentials, but as soon as the user is locked and try again to log in, wso2is redirect to the /authenticationendpoint/retry.do page which display a simple error message.

What can i do to display a custom error message on the same login page if the user is already locked but try to log in ?

Note that i have this configuration enabled in the deployment.toml file :

```
[authentication.authenticator.basic.parameters]
showAuthFailureReason = true
```

and the only error i have is this line :

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} - Authentication failed exception! Account is locked for user xxx@xxx in user store PRIMARY in tenant carbon.super. Cannot login until the account is unlocked.
```

Thanks for your help

I tried to follow the wso2is documentation https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/customizing-authentication-error-messages/.

I tried to play with the service-providers too

Answer (score 0):

This improvement was already identified[1] and this was fixed from WSO2 IS 6.0 onwards. You can switch to the latest product version or otherwise, you can apply a patch with the fixes mentioned in the issue.

[1]https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/12175

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for your help, I managed to get it working in our development environment, but it stopped working as soon as I deployed the version in our pre-production environment. Is there any configuration to add in the wso2is interface, like services-providers for example?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, Hope you have ported these fixes (https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-local-auth-basicauth/pull/113, https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/3622 & https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/pull/2257). And after adding these changes did you add  the following configs to the deployment.toml file?      `showAuthFailureReasonOnLoginPage = true `